# How to solve this fuzzy logic problem?

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

$\textbf{Problem}$ :

Show directly that if $f, g \in A u t(\mathbb{I}),$ and
$$
f^{-1}((f(x)+f(y)-1) \vee 0)=g^{-1}((g(x)+g(y)-1) \vee 0)
$$
for all $x, y \in[0,1],$ then $f=g$

$\textbf{Note}$ : $A u t(\mathbb{I})$ is the set of all functions $f$ from [0,1] to [0,1] that are one-to-one and onto, and such that $f(x) \leq f(y)$ if and only if $x \leq y .$

Answer (score 1):

(Getting another question off the unanswered list.)

Suppose that $f,g\in\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb I)$, and

$$f^{-1}\Big(\big(f(x)+f(y)-1\big)\lor 0\Big)=g^{-1}\Big(\big(g(x)+g(y)-1\big)\lor 0\Big)$$

for all $x,y\in[0,1]$; since $f$ and $g$ are bijections, so are $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$, and therefore

$$\big(f(x)+f(y)-1\big)\lor 0=\big(g(x)+g(y)-1\big)\lor 0$$

for all $x,y\in[0,1]$. Note also that since $f$ and $g$ are order-preserving and surjective, $f(1)=g(1)=1$. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
f(x)&=f(x)\lor 0\\
&=\big(f(x)+f(1)-1\big)\lor 0\\
&=\big(g(x)+g(1)-1\big)\lor 0\\
&=g(x)\lor 0\\
&=g(x)
\end{align*}$$

for each $x\in[0,1]$, i.e., $f=g$.